# Framework for developing front-end with back-end as REST

Tags: wordpress, drupal, joomla, content-management-system, php

Currently I'm developing the back-end of a PHP application using Recess Framework. I'm almost done and I now need to do the front-end. I have many alternatives and I prefer a CMS. The alternatives in my knowledge are Drupal or Wordpress. The problem is that I've never used Drupal and Wordpress(or any better). Thus I don't which one to choose to develop the app to interact with the REST interface.Can you help me in choosing the best CMS for interacting with the REST interface

Comment: I think there's a disconnect on what you are calling a front-end. With PHP apps most people think of HTML/CSS/Javascript as the Front-end. Most CMSs aren't geared towards talking to other interfaces without a lot of retrofitting. It seems like you should choose a lower level PHP framework to make your middle-end. Are you trying to talk to the REST API directly from the client (browser) or do you want a PHP middle-end?

Comment: Google "middle-end". It's the tier between the browser front-end and a data backend like a REST API. If you want to connect directly from the browser to the REST API then you likely need to look into Javascript frameworks like Spine.js, backbone.js, knockout.js, etc. CMSs won't help you here as they are usually tightly coupled and expect to talk to the database directly. It might help to describe what you want your front-end to do when it connects to the API. I think this topic is becoming better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If your application is going to be distributed to many clients who will run their own instances  then I would go with wordpress. Wp is more popular and hence more people will be able to support it.

On the other hand if you application is going to be hosted by you or just one or two instances then I would go with drupal.

Both wp and drupal can give you what you want but drupal is better presented and structured for custom programmes in my opinion.

What is you application about ? Chances are drupal has a module already for it .

cheers,
Vishal

Answer (score 0):

For Joomla, here's a basic start on a REST API you might look at:

[GitHib](https://github.com/idea34/Joomla-REST-API)

[Depends on what you want to make available via REST... User data, content etc]

For WP and others, you might consider something like [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/)
using an approach [like this](http://codingthis.com/programming/php/using-the-slim-php-framework-for-developing-rest-apis/)